# My Code Returns the correct Row (i think) but read writes to the wrong row Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to:

- Find the Row number the Value from Cell `'PENALTY LINEUP ENTRY'!B10` on the sheet called Penalties
- Copy the Data for that person '`PENALTY LINEUP ENTRY'!C10:J11` to the adjacent cells on the Penalties sheet.

The problem is that the data gets written to the wrong row and I don't know why.

Here is my spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aKcfX4u91aYFMPMOJBSlx92JmhRGH3MeVjLenxbEtAw/edit?usp=sharing

Below is my code:

```
function next_jam() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PENALTY LINEUP ENTRY');
  var Psheet = ss.getSheetByName('Penalties');
  var Jam = sheet.getRange('D5');
  var JamValue = Jam.getValue();
  var Period = sheet.getRange('D2').getValue();
  var H_J =sheet.getRange('B10').getValue();
  var H_P =sheet.getRange('B13').getValue();
  var H_B1 =sheet.getRange('B16').getValue();
  var H_B2 =sheet.getRange('B19').getValue();
  var H_B3 =sheet.getRange('B22').getValue();
  var A_J =sheet.getRange('N10').getValue();
  var A_P =sheet.getRange('N13').getValue();
  var A_B1 =sheet.getRange('N16').getValue();
  var A_B2 =sheet.getRange('N19').getValue();
  var A_B3 =sheet.getRange('N22').getValue();
  var H_Jp = sheet.getRange('C10:J11');
  var H_JpValues = H_Jp.getValues(); 
  var H_Pp = sheet.getRange('C13:J14');
  var H_PpValues = H_Pp.getValues(); 
  var H_B1p = sheet.getRange('C16:J17');
  var H_B1pValues = H_B1p.getValues(); 
  var H_B2p = sheet.getRange('C19:J20');
  var H_B2pValues = H_B2p.getValues(); 
  var H_B3p = sheet.getRange('C22:J23');
  var H_B3pValues = H_B3p.getValues();
  var A_Jp = sheet.getRange('O10:V11');
  var A_JpValues = A_Jp.getValues(); 
  var A_Pp = sheet.getRange('O13:V14');
  var A_PpValues = A_Pp.getValues(); 
  var A_B1p = sheet.getRange('O16:V17');
  var A_B1pValues = A_B1p.getValues(); 
  var A_B2p = sheet.getRange('O19:V20');
  var A_B2pValues = A_B2p.getValues(); 
  var A_B3p = sheet.getRange('O22:V32')
  var A_B3pValues = A_B3p.getValues();  
  var H_P1 = Psheet.getRange('A1:H43');
  var H_P2 = Psheet.getRange('AC1:AJ43');
  var A_P1 = Psheet.getRange('P1:W43');
  var A_P2 = Psheet.getRange('AR1:AY43');
  var H_P1values = H_P1.getValues();
  var H_P2values = H_P2.getValues();
  var A_P1values = A_P1.getValues();
  var A_P2values = A_P2.getValues();


//   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PENALTY LINEUP ENTRY');
//   var Psheet = ss.getSheetByName('Penalties');
//   var Jam = sheet.getRange('E5').getValue();
//   var Period = sheet.getRange('E2').getValue();
//   var H_J =sheet.getRange('B10').getValue();
//   var H_Jp = sheet.getRange('C10:J11').getValues();
//   var H_P1 = Psheet.getRange('A4:H43');
//   var H_P1values = H_P1.getValues();
Logger.log('This is the CURRENT HOME JAMMER = '+H_J);
  for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    var row = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < 21; j++) {     
      if (H_P1values[i][j] == H_J && Period == 1) {
        row = H_P1values[i][j+1];

        Logger.log('This is the Row the HOME JAMMER is on = '+i); // This is your row number
```

Comment: I can help you with that, just sended you a request on your spreadsheet.

Comment: @JSmith - I am not sure if that is acceptable behaviour in StackOverflow community. It would be better if an explanation of the answer is provided here for future readers.

Comment: I would prefer an answer here rather than live troubleshooting.  If work needs to be done to solve the problem please Make a Copy of the spreadsheet and work on that, posting the answer here.

Comment: @jainashish I don't know what prevents me from asking to help live. I've always done that and it's more easy. Instead of commenting for three hours and having to copy down the spreadsheet down. It's not me who is having a problem. But if it's written somewhere please let me know.

Comment: ok I will be free for 30 min from 1 pm GMT i will be on the spreadsheet then

Comment: @Clinch  Welcome. How did you get on with the problem that you posted on StackOverflow? Did you resolve things or are you still looking for assistance?